# Error message when calling model derivative API - but I have a subscription

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I had a trial account and the paid APIs expired, then I bought a subscription which was setup in the last day or so.  But, when I call to transform a drawing (simple AutoCAD drawing in a bucket) I get the error below.

```
{
"developerMessage": "You are not allowed to use this API because your Forge trial is expired.",
"moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
"errorCode": "ERR-004"}
```

please advise.  My account in account management does show that I have an active subscription, and I see 100 credits allotted to my named user account.  Application Client ID is shown in the image below

[image: Application ID]

Answer (score 0):

this appears to be working now.  I do not know if something got jiggled on the backend or not, if so thank you!